# Windows 8 package.appxmanifest Can't add my own logo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-store

I exported Construct2 project to Windows 8 Store app. I have a problem with setting my own logo and splash screen. In file *package.appxmanifest* I want to change it but when I inserted my owns PNGs, there appeared some red signs. I tried again to insert my logos, but it doesn't work. When I build the project on the splash screen there are default pics. How can I fix it?
[image: s]

[image: s]

Comment: make sure that your scaled assets are properly named http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263244.aspx.

You may have to clear incorrect values from the package.appmanifest by editing the xml directly. The designer sometimes chokes on unexpected asset names

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the dimensions of your logo are correct and that the logo file is included in the project itself (not just in the right folder - right click the Assets folder and select Add Existing to add the file in the project).

An important help could be hovering over the stop icon with your mouse which usually gives a tooltip with the cause of the problem.